# Multiplex external HTTP requests from a Django view

Tags: django, python-2.7, asynchronous, httprequest

We have a heavily-used Django app (Django 1.9, python 2.7) with a view that makes 5 or so independent HTTP requests, in serial, to an external web service. The results of these external requests are then used to build the view's response.

The view takes longer to respond than we'd like. The external requests are not interdependent--we could take their responses in any order. What would be the simplest way to parallelize these requests?

Comment: do you need the result of the requests to construct the response to the client?

Comment: Yes. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) does exactly what you're looking for but any async request library will do.

Comment: requests-futures appears to be Python 3.4+ only. I need 2.7.

Comment: Maybe I misread the docs... requests-futures might work. Care to write that up as an answer?